# How to get url for facebook profile photo in contact

Tags: apex, integration, callout, facebook

I am trying get the url for facebook profile photo which appears in contact detail page.
I am able get the photoUrl of Contact by SOQL query:
select photourl from contact where id = 'contact Id'
response = /services/images/photo/contactId
If I use this in workbench REST Explores I am getting the proper response with facebook profile image url.
But how to do this Rest call in apex.
I tried :
public String getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {
    // Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();

```
// Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint    
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();    
req.setEndpoint(url);    
req.setMethod('GET');

// Send the request, and return a response    
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res);
return res.getBody();
```

}
but getting bad request error.

Answer (score 1):

In Apex you should Query directly for the Contact:

```
Contact c = [SELECT PhotoUrl FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId LIMIT 1];
```

No need to make a ReST callout from Apex.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am doing this, but i am getting response like :  /services/images/photo/contactId
But i want the facebook photo url like: 
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-1/p120x120/12646937_940753299347195_8302740519281199104_n.jpg?oh=ec7c65a85b95422ca191a6ca69e67511&oe=576A878E&__gda__=1462897915_110224746e3a07d9fc45c26003c4b448
This i am getting in workbench rest explore but how to implement in apex.

Comment: So the full link would be the server along with your result. You can get the server using `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();`