# How to get full image URL of PhotoUrl in Contacts using jsforce

Tags: rest-api, contact, url, images, jsforce

I use nodejs/**jsforce** to connect to Sf API.

In the "Contacts" one of the fields is retrieved as a string path

```
PhotoUrl:"/services/images/photo/003o.....AAV"
```

But that's not very handy if I want to display the **actual image**. I would expect smth like `mysite.com/.../myimage.jpg`

If I login to SF and open this contact detail there is a correct full absolut image url `mysite.com/.../myimage.jpg`
So question is there a specific setting of jsforce plugin or Sf API itself to get full url ?

I've checked this question - [How to get url for facebook profile photo in contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108127/how-to-get-url-for-facebook-profile-photo-in-contact) - but I not sure how to apply this in case with jSForce API access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create the full URL in this way. After the login API call or OAuth2 authorization, you can get Salesforce access token and its **instance URL**. Use this URL in conjunction with PhotoUrl (instanceURL+PhotoUrl) to create the full contact Image URL.

Comment: I've tried this. but I only have following props there - ```{ id: '005o0000....',  organizationId: '005o0000....',  url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/...'}``` does it mean that I need to fill in the `instanceUrl` field somewhere in SF admin UI ?

Comment: No, you should receive it automatically in the response after the login call. As per JsForce documentation, you should get it as `conn.instanceUrl` https://jsforce.github.io/document/

Comment: Yes I see this part of the doc, but if it's not there? However the connection itself in my case is OK - I can execute queries normally. What that `conn.instanceUrl` missing may mean - wrong access level or wrongly configured Sf ?

Comment: Sorry, do you have any idea how to get the instanceUrl ? Or why It may be not visible ?